# Using Selenium 2's IWebDriver to interact with elements on the page

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-iedriver

I'm using Selenium's `IWebDriver` to write Unit Tests in C#.

Such is an example:

```
IWebDriver defaultDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
var ddl = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));
```

The last line retrieves the `select` HTML element wrapped in a `IWebElement`.

I **need a way to simulate selection to a specific `option` in that `select` list** but I can't figure out how to do it.

---

Upon some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476941/using-selenium-for-selecting-an-option-on-a-select-with-optgroup), I found examples where people are using the `ISelenium DefaultSelenium` class to accomplish the following, but I am not making use of this class because I'm doing everything with `IWebDriver` and `INavigation` (from `defaultDriver.Navigate()`).

I also noticed that `ISelenium DefaultSelenium` contains a ton of other methods that aren't available in the concrete implementations of `IWebDriver`.

So is there any way I can use `IWebDriver` and `INavigation` in conjunction with `ISelenium DefaultSelenium` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ZloiAdun mentions, there is a lovely new Select class in the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace. That's one of the best ways to access a selection element and it's options because it's api is so easy. Let's say you've got a web page that looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Disposable Page</title>
</head>
    <body >
        <select id="select">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

You're code to access the select would look like this. Note how I create the Select object by passing a normal IWebElement to it's constructor.  You have plenty of methods on the Select object. [Take a look at the source](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/support/src/csharp/webdriver-support/UI/Select.cs) for more information, until it gets properly documented.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace Selenium2
{
    class SelectExample
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.example.com");

            //note how here's i'm passing in a normal IWebElement to the Select
            // constructor
            Select select = new Select(driver.FindElement(By.Id("select")));
            IList<IWebElement> options = select.GetOptions();
            foreach (IWebElement option in options)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(option.Text);
            }
            select.SelectByValue("audi");

            //This is only here so you have time to read the output and 
            System.Console.ReadLine();
            driver.Quit();

        }
    }
}
```

A couple things to note about the Support class however. Even if you downloaded the latest beta, the support DLL won't be there. The Support package has a relatively long history in the Java libraries (that's where PageObject lives) but it's still pretty fresh in the .Net driver. Fortunately, it's really easy to build from source. I [pulled from SVN](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout) then referenced the WebDriver.Common.dll from the beta download and built in C# Express 2008. This class hasn't been as well tested as some of the other classes, but my example worked in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

There's a few other things that I should point out based on your code above. Firstly the line you were using to find the select element

```
driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));
```

is going to find **all** select elements. you should probably use `driver.FindElement`, without the 's'.

Also, very rarely would you use INavigation directly. You'll do most of your navigation like `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");`

Lastly, `DefaultSelenium` is the way to access the older Selenium 1.x apis. Selenium 2 is a pretty significant departure from Selenium 1, so unless you're trying to migrate old tests to the new Selenium 2 api (often referred to as the WebDriver api) you won't use DefaultSelenium.

Comment: +1 The `Select` class, as linked by ZloiAdun did the job, but I'm accepting this answer because you provided more information.  Since the `Select` is not yet available in the public dll, I'm currently using the class and the exception linked by ZloiAdun.

As regards the `FindElements`, I need to use that one because is more than 1 `select` that I want retrieved.

Finally, thanks for mentioning the issue as regards `DefaultSelenium`, although I have a follow question to that;  Is there any way to make use of the tons of methods that `DefaultSelenium` offers?

Comment: +1 for clarifying IWebDriver being the way to go with 2.x.  Just starting out and most of the demos I could find use DefaultSelenium.

Answer (score 2):

You should get all `option` elements from your `select` using `ddl.FindElements(By.TagName("option"));`. Then you can iterate through the returned collection and select required item(s) by using `SetSelected` method of the `IWebElement`

**Update**: It seems that there's now a C# implementation of the `Select` in WebDriver - previously it was in Java only. Please take a look at its [code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#2tHw6m3DZzo/trunk/support/src/csharp/webdriver-support/UI/Select.cs) and it is easier to use this class

Comment: `IWebElement` does not have a method `SetSelected`.  There is a method called `Select` but for my case, it's not doing anything.

Comment: I am not using C#, so I can miss the method names - sorry for that. Have you tried using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.Select class? Are you using the Select() on the option of the select?