# How do I get this div tag using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<div id="ctl00_ContentHolder_vs_ValidationSummary" class="errorblock">
    <p><strong>The following errors were found:</strong></p>
    <ul><input type="hidden" Name="SummaryErrorCmsIds" Value="E024|E012|E014" />
        <li>Please select a title.</li>
        <li>Please key in your first name.</li>
        <li>Please key in your last name.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to capture the text having value of E024 E012 and E014 and write it in to an Excel file.

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```cs
string val1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'errorblock'/ value = 'E024|E012|E014'")).Text;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to capture? The value of 'Value' parameter? Or something else?

Comment: Yes I want to capture the value of Value ie Please select a title , Please key in your first name and Please key in your last name . These value to be captured and write it in to excel

Answer (score 1):

In java -

```
String x = driver.findElement(By.name("SummaryErrorCmsIds")).getAttribute("Value"));
```

Comment: Hi I tried getting only the null value in String X. can you please suggest any other way ?

Comment: Yes the name is correct , you can see my html code in the question.I want to capture the value of Value ie Please select a title , Please key in your first name and Please key in your last name . These value to be captured and write it in to excel. But string X returning Null value

Comment: why don't you add id to your li elements like <li id ="E012"> and find by id? It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use XPATH

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("...\li")).Text; (OR)

 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("...\li")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're selecting the wrong elements. I have no idea what your html looks like but try looking into FindElements and try doing a lookup by 'li'

Take a look here: [Using Selenium 2's IWebDriver to interact with elements on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657465/using-selenium-2s-iwebdriver-to-interact-with-elements-on-the-page)

Comment: Yes , I think so.. Can you please provide solution for this. My HTML code is in my question I want to capture the value of Value ie Please select a title , Please key in your first name and Please key in your last name . These value to be captured and write it in to excel

Comment: I'd love to help more but see if you can use what I gave you then tell me if what you're doing works more.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you meant but my example solution would be:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("errorblock")).findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
List<WebElement> values = element.findElements(By.tagName("li"))

for (WebElement value : values)
{
   String valueString = value.getText();
   //write to excel or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var div = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'ValidationSummary')]"));
    var targetElement = div.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@name, 'SummaryErrorCmsIds')]"));
// or var targetElement = div.FindElement(By.TagName("input"))
```

And then get info you need from this element.

Answer (score 0):

IN C# it should be as follows.

```
String var1= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'ValidationSummary')]")).Text;
```